Transient protection on mono jack
I am working on a circuit where a relay controls the output of a mono jack. Recently, I was informed that it might be necessary to incorporate ESD or other transient voltage protection into connectors that may come into human contact. However, I have found limited resources on implementing ESD protection specifically for mono/stereo jacks in this type of configuration.
Below are images of the circuit for reference:


In this setup, the transistor receives a signal from the MCU, which activates the relay, thereby closing the switch for the mono output (U8). I have placed a TVS diode to ground on the mono jack, but I am unsure if this is the correct method for protecting the mono jack against ESD.
Could anyone provide insights or recommendations on the appropriate way to implement ESD protection for this circuit?
Also, is there a way to implement ESD without connecting to GND, to keep the relay's switch closure isolated?
Thank you for any assistance.
Here is an updated simplified image of the schematic, with the TVS diode in another possible location:


The connector and relay do not need ESD protection - it's the signal source and you don't tell what it is. The signals on connectors always have a reference and it is unclear what it is but the ESD protection should be between signal and signal ground, not some unrelated ground. Also the flyback diode from the relay coil is missing so likely first time you turn on and off the transistor it gets damaged. Please zoom out a little and tell what you are trying to achieve.

More specifically, ESD protection goes between inputs/outputs and ground (plane) of the circuit being protected. || Why isn't the sleeve hard grounded? Surely switching tip would be as simple? Since the plug touches the sleeve (opening or spring) first, it's highly likely ESD current flows there first, and then tip might only receive a fraction thereafter.

What is the max frequency you hope to pass through the connector? And the voltage?

@justme The signal source is a 3.3V signal I/O from an ESP32 MCU. There is a fly back IC array used for the relay. I have updated the schematic in the post. In order to protect the internals of the circuit, would you recommend placing the TVS diode across the output of the relay, like in the updated image.
Overall, I’m trying to determine what would be the best location to add transient voltage suppression to my system in order to mitigate any transient voltages that could get introduced at my connector.

@ursusd8 The mono jack would plug into different devices so it’s hard to say, buts lets limit it to DC values of less than 12V and under 1.5A.
